# Unit testing with mocks (PHP)

Tags: php, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I have a class like:

```
class Foo {
    function getCurrentBar() {
        $model = Query::findByPk($this->getSession()->get('current_bar')); // Pseudocode...

        return $model;
    }
}
```

So basically there's one bar at a time in my application and it is stored in the session as an integer. I frequently call a helper function which will find the model instance, it makes a db query. There is caching as well, but that won't matter now.

My question is this: how do I unit test **with** this? There are classes that I test that need this. I guess I could alter the session to contain the id but then it means I need to have a corresponding model in the database.

Would the best approach be to add a method `setCurrentBar()` just for unit testing purposes? Then I could mock a bar object and set it and it will be used for all unit tests. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is indeed dependency injection, but the dependency you want to control is the *source* of bars, not the bar itself.

```
class Foo {
  private $query;

  function __construct($query)
  {
    $this->query = $query;
  }

  function getCurrentBar() {
    $model = $this->query->findByPk($this->getSession()->get('current_bar')); // Pseudocode...

    return $model;
  }
}
```

So in your production code you have

```
$query = new Query() // assuming findByPk() is made a normal non-static method
$realFoo = new Foo($query);
```

but for unit testing...

```
$testFoo = new Foo(new MockQuery());
```

where `MockQuery` is a mock version of your `Query` class which returns mock *bars*.

Comment: I'm using Propel for PHP, and it would feel kind of weird to inject a mocked Propel Query object, is it?

Comment: @rFactor I agree, DI does feel weird. You're passing things to a constructor which don't fully belong to the object being created, but the benefits outweigh the weirdness. btw the Propel devs are big on testing - I'd be surprised if they don't have a way of mocking things.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Pass the Bar instance to the Foo constructor

```
class Foo
{
    private _bar;

    function __construct (Bar $bar)
    {
        $this->_bar = $bar;
    }

    public function getCurrentBar()
    {
        return $this->_bar;
    }
}
```

Then you can inject your mock Bar Object when you run your test.

Answer (score 0):

You could also choose to test a partial mock object, as an interim until a DI system is in place.

```
class Foo {
    function getCurrentBar() {
        $model = $this->getQueryResult($this->getSession()->get('current_bar')); // Pseudocode...
        return $model;
    }
    function getQueryResult($queryParams)
    {
        return Query::findByPk($queryParams);
    }
}
```

Then do a test that looks a bit like this...

```
$myObjectToTest = $this->getMock('Foo', array('getQueryResult'), array(), '', true, true, true);
$myObjectToTest->expects($this->once())
               ->method('getQueryResult')
               ->with($whateverTheQueryParametersAre)
               ->will($this->returnValue($someResult));
$myObjectToTest->getCurrentBar();
```